# Is there a way to trigger a directive on a dom element when the scope changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have the following markup:

```
<div do-something>
    <div> {{element.Name}} </div>
</div>
```

and the doSomething directive returns

```
angular.module('mainModule').directive('doSomething', function ()
    return function () {
        console.log('something changed!');
    };
});
```

Can I get the directive to fire (i.e. log 'something changed') whenever `element` is changed?

Comment: Can you add the complete code of your directive?

Comment: @SamV I want to avoid using $watch in order to tie this to a directive that I can apply on any element.

Comment: Please don't mark this as duplicate, I want to avoid using $watch and $apply.